# Within .NET Core DI, how do singleton lifetime services behave with concurrent requests?

Tags: .net, performance, .net-core, dependency-injection, singleton

Within the context of .NET Core DI, if a service is registered as a Singleton (the lifetime, not to be confused with the pattern), will it be able to handle multiple concurrent requests?

Documentation says "every subsequent request uses the same instance." Let's say our data access implementation is registered as such. Does that imply it won't scale and handle concurrent requests, and each will essentially queue up to use the service?

Answer (score 0):

> Does that imply it won't scale and handle concurrent requests, and each will essentially queue up to use the service?

Not at all. When you declare a service as `Singleton` (or other scopes) you **JUST** define its lifetime (create and dispose behavior) for DI. Not more, not less. It doesn't have any relation or impact on accessing manner of threads and requests to service. So you have to pay attention to concurrency issues of your service and define locks everywhere on code that isn't threadsafe.

> Let's say our data access implementation is registered as such

Specifically if you're using ORMs like Entity Framework you should know that its `DbContext` is not threadsafe and declaring it as `Singleton` causes many concurrency issues and should be avoided.

Answer (score -2):

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options):

*Singleton lifetime services (AddSingleton) are created the first time they're requested (or when Startup.ConfigureServices is run and an instance is specified with the service registration). Every subsequent request uses the same instance. If the app requires singleton behavior, allowing the service container to manage the service's lifetime is recommended. Don't implement the singleton design pattern and provide user code to manage the object's lifetime in the class.*

According to the statement above, the requests as you mentioned in your question will be queued up.

But if you think from a performance point of view, your alternative would be to

1. Instantiate the object
2. Run your method
3. Garbage collect the object

You do not only pay a performance toll in the beginning by instantiating the objects but you also require more effort from the GC when collecting them.

If you have some very heavy CPU operation in your singleton service that is used multiple times per request it might actually make some sense to reconsider your approach and go towards a scoped lifetime.

But overall creating a singleton service is still the best solution, when it is possible, from a performance point of view.

Comment: "the requests as you mentioned in your question will be queued up." This statement is incorrect. There is no automatic synchronization (or locking) going on with Singleton objects and requests will *not* be queued because of it. Locking should be implemented manually if required.

Comment: @Steven if an object is locked the execution will be stopped for rest of the requests until the object is realized. The is what I meant by "queue up" using the questions terminology

Comment: *If* you use locking, that will indeed ensure that execution is queued. But that is not what will happen with singletons. Only its initial creation is protected with some sort of lock to guarantee that only a single instance is created. After that, any thread is permitted to call all of the singleton's methods in parallel. Or -at least- there is *absolutely nothing* in the MS.DI DI Container (or any other container to my knowledge) that would block parallel access to a singleton's method.